# VBscript HttpRequest's ResponseText never update for the same URL

Tags: caching, vbscript, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, httpresponse

I was creating a Demo using VBsciprt, proving that "The Software" has the capability to send Http Request. I used an existing example that I wrote before:

```vb
On Error Resume Next

Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.Open "GET", requestURL, False
o.send
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description, 16, "Error"
Else
    MsgBox o.responseText, 0, Response
End If
```

However, when I did unit testing, I found out that if you send request to the same url address, you will always get the same result - however, the result should be different, tested and proved.

I searched on the Internet and tried to add `o.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"` and it is not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just answer my question here...

Add `Pragma` and `If-Modified-Since` will solve the issue

```vb
...
o.Open "GET", requestURL, False
o.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
o.setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
o.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
o.send
...
```

Anyone got better ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a "better idea", but using `WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1` instead of `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` appears to always get the updated page (or at least the timeout is much shorter).